# Use of ng-model incorrectly makes slider bar start at middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have a slider bar and want the its gripper starts at the left side.

Here is what I tried to do, but it doesn't work.

```
 <input type="range" id="{{'sa' + q.id}}" value="0" min="0" max="10" ng-model="q.answer" style="clear:both;"/><span >{{q.answer}}</span>
```

As you can see, I set the value of that slider bar to 0 but the gripper still shows at the middle of it.

Do you have any clue?

---

**Update**

I tried to remove ng-model="q.answer" and found the problem is fixed. But I do need ng-model to do the data-binding.

Do you have any clue to stop this happening?

---

**Update 2**

I actually have a list of questions to add an attribute, "answer",and set its value to 0.
Here is the code.

```
$http.get("http://my.azurewebsites.net/api/Questions").success(function (data) {

        $scope.questions = data;

        angular.forEach($scope.questions, function (value, key) {
            console.log(this);
          //  how to write the code to add an attribute "answer" to the question object and set its value to 0?

        });
```

---

**Update 3 : Solution**

I found the issue was caused by the default value of q.answer and thus changed this value, here is how I did it.

```
 $scope.questions[key].answer = 0;
```

Thanks to your input :)

Comment: It's starting for me on left side http://jsfiddle.net/haep5sf4/ . Maybe, something with your angular model?

Comment: can you add a demo, where it's starting from middle?

Comment: hi @monkeyinsight I found it works in my other pages, so I'd like to guess its something about the AngularJs???

Comment: This fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1nj13y8d shows it to be working as expected. Check the front-end output to make sure something isn't updating the value to 5. Otherwise please provide an example. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Franva I bet it is. Check preset values in model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably assigned a value to the scope model `q.answer`. As shown here in the fiddle, assigning a value of 0 to the model fixes the problem.

```
$scope.q = {
    answer: 3, // answer has an initial value
    start: 0 //set to 0 like this
};
```

[**JSFiddle of slider values**](http://jsfiddle.net/happysmiles/keagd91p/1/)

Comment: hi khakiout, thank you for your answer. I think it's almost there, but in my case, I have to change a list of question. Please see my update, thx